# Unit testing xUnit with JSON files data

Tags: c#, xunit, .net-5

I want to unit test my technical analysis indicators. I have historical candle data downloaded in JSON format.

1. What is the correct way to load the JSON data into xUnit and re-use it on multiple methods? All I want is to be able to use the historical data (`List<OHLCV>`) from all these methods in `IndicatorTests.cs`.
2. Is it important to move `Data()` into a fixture? Since my indicators will be tested in a same file `IndicatorTests.cs`?
3. How do I find the JSON files because they are inside the project and not in `/bin/Debug`. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is kinda looking for them in `/bin/Debug`, which is wrong.

[image]

```cs
public class IndicatorTests
{
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> Data()
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Data\TRX_USDT-5m.json");

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            throw new FileNotFoundException($"The historical data file '{filePath}' was not found.");

        var data = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        var deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<decimal>>>(data);

        var candles = deserializedData.Select(e => new OHLCV()
        {
            Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds((long)e[0]).DateTime,
            Open = e[1],
            High = e[2],
            Low = e[3],
            Close = e[4],
            Volume = e[5]
        });

        foreach (var candle in candles ?? Enumerable.Empty<OHLCV>())
        {
            yield return new[] { candle };
        }
    }

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(Data))]
    public void Test1(List<OHLCV> candle)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(candle);
    }

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(Data))]
    public void Test2(List<OHLCV> candle)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(candle);
    }

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(Data))]
    public void Test3(List<OHLCV> candle)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(candle);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd create a service that reads the data in from file and provides the data. Then I'd use xUnit.DependencyInjection to make that service a singleton, so the files are read only once. And finally inject the service to the tests that need the data.

Comment: @Fildor, even that way I don't know how to read `Project_dir\Data`. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` returns `/bin/Debug` instead.